# Using LINQ expression to get previous element from a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a LINQ expression based on the following scenario:

```
public class Meeting
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public bool Selected { get; set; }    
}

List<Meeting> Meetings
```

**Using LINQ expression, how to retrieve the metting occurring just before the first one which is selected ?**

For example in the liste below I need to retrieve the meeting Id 2.

- Id:1 Date:11/1 Selected: false
- Id:2 Date:12/1 Selected: false
- Id:3 Date:13/1 Selected: **true**
- Id:4 Date:14/1 Selected: **true**

Comment: So you need to take `Id:2 Date:12/1 Selected: false`, right?

Comment: That's absolutely right

Comment: You can use `TakeWhile` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534804)) and `LastOrDefault` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb504095)), e.g. `meetings.TakeWhile(meeting => meeting.Selected == false).LastOrDefault()`.

Comment: Is it possible there might be `selected: false` ones after the `selected:true` ones?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile) and [`LastOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault):

```
var meeting = Meetings.TakeWhile(m => !m.Selected)
                      .LastOrDefault();

if (meeting != null) 
{
    // Use the meeting
}
else
{
    // The first meeting was selected, or there are no meetings
}
```

`TakeWhile` basically stops when it hits the first item that doesn't match the predicate - it's like a `Where` that stops early, in other words.

You need to be careful with ordering though - you're pretty much assuming there's a bunch of unselected meetings, followed by selected ones.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `TakeWhile` and `LastOrDefault`.

```
Meetings.TakeWhile(m => !m.Selected).LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: @musefan what's the difference between TakeWhile() and Where()?

Comment: @Werlang: `Where` will continue for the whole sequence. Imagine a sequence of meetings where the selected property sequence is { false, false, true, true, false } - if you use `Where(...).Last(...)` you'd get the element 4 instead of element 1.

Comment: @musefan OP has stated "...how to retrieve the metting occurring just `before the first one` which is selected ?"